# C++: how to do "map" of Scheme

Tags: c++, functional-programming

Below is a sample code of Scheme (correct me if i'm wrong):

```
(define (translate points delta)
    (map 
        (lambda (x)
            (+ x delta)
        )
        points 
    )
)
```

basically it defines a lambda function that add `delta` to input `x`, then apply it to each item of `points`.

I found such feature quite interesting that it omits all the iterators and etc.

Is it possible to do such "map" in C++, in an elegant way?

Update according to the reply:

To be more specific, is there a way to implement such "map" function of Scheme, in C++, so that it could be used elegantly? Maybe a template function named "map" that accept function pointer / functor, and a container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no predefined exact equivalent... but it's not difficult to write:

```
template<typename T, typename F>
T mymap(const T& container, F f) {
    T result;
    for (auto const & x : container) {
        result.push_back(f(x));
    }
    return result;
}

std::vector<int> translate(const std::vector<int>& x, int delta) {
    return mymap(x, [=](int x){return x+delta;});
}
```

Something similar to scheme `map` is `std::transform`, but requires you to provide an output iterator of where to store the transformed elements.

The C++ standard library is built around the concept of iterator pairs (for example even for `sort` you don't pass a container but a pair of iterators).  I personally don't think this is such a great idea, but it's the way the language was designed.

Comment: thanks, i think this is the closest to "map" in Scheme

Answer (score 4):

The closest translation of your code in idiomatic C++ would be using [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) with a [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter):

```
std::vector<point> points{…};
std::vector<point> output;
// optional, may improve performance:
output.reserve(points.size());

auto lambda = [=](point x) { return x + delta; };
std::transform(begin(points), end(points), std::back_inserter(output), lambda);
```

Here, `lambda` captures its surrounding scope by value – this is indicated by the `[=]` prefix. This makes it possible to use `delta` inside it.

However, for `T -> T` transformations you would usually use an in-place variant instead of pushing values into a new container:

```
std::vector<point> points{…};

auto lambda = [=](point x) { return x + delta; };
std::transform(begin(points), end(points), begin(points), lambda);
```

Answer (score 2):

The C++ version is called `std::transform`.